# How to marquee ListView in android?

Tags: android, listview, marquee

I want to marquee my listview in android up to end of my listview item and at the end repeat marquee my listview. Tell me how I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

you want to marquee listview or listview's items like textview ?for textview you can use this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fact"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Loading... More text to see if it spans or not and want more">

    <requestFocus
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
</TextView>
```

Comment: ListView not ListView Item.